# mysql_fetch_array display issues

Tags: php, mysql

The script below is to search the db for the query
 ( $matric_no ), so that it returns the names(first, last,
 other name) and other student informations. It works fine if it only
returns one row , but whenever two or more rows are returned
 the names (which are the same for all the rows) are also iterated the same times as the number of rows returned. How can i
  make it return just a single instance of the student names
  irrespective of the no of affected rows?

I have also tried using LIMT and GROUP BY but to no avail.

I typed on a mobile, hence the irregular formatting. I meant no disrespect to the community.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
  <?php require('includes/dbconnect.php'); ?>
 <?php require 'includes/header.inc.php'; ?>
<?php
 $matric_no = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matric_no']) ;
 if ( $_POST['matric_no'] == "")
{
 echo"<div id=\"contentRight\">";
 echo"<div id=\"msg\">" ;
 echo "You didn't enter a <span style=\"color:red\"> Matric Number</span>";
 echo"</div>" ;
 echo"</div>" ;
  exit();
 }
  $query = "SELECT matric_no
 FROM main_table
     WHERE main_table.matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]'";
   $result = mysql_query($query) ;
  $duplicates = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ($duplicates < 1)
{
 echo"<div id=\"contentRight\">";
echo"<idv id=\"msg\">" ;
 echo "You dont have a record for <span style=\"color:red\">
   $matric_no</span>" ;
 echo"</div>" ;
  echo"</div>" ;
  exit();
 }
{
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT main_table.matric_no ,
  main_table.session,
  main_table.semester , main_table.course_name ,
  (test+exam+practical) AS Total,
  students.first_name, students.last_name, students.other_name,
  students.level
  FROM main_table INNER JOIN students ON
  main_table.matric_no = students.matric_no
   WHERE main_table.matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]'")
  or die (mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       echo $row["matric_no"] ;                   
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row["session"]; echo "<br />";
  echo $row["semester"];
  echo "<br />";
   echo $row["course_name"];
   echo "<br />";
    echo $row["first_name"];
  echo "<br />";
    echo $row["last_name"];
  echo "<br />";
    echo $row["other_name"];
  echo "<br />";
    echo $row["level"]; echo "<br />";
   }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: this is an sql error.  Please show the structure of your tables so that we can show you how your query should look to get the data you want. You can remove any php stuff here.  All we really need is the query and the tables.

Comment: Do you have an error in this code or Do you want to change the way it displays?

Comment: @prasad

Yes i'll want to change the way it displays. Currently there are no SQL Errors. But in it's display, there were 4 rows affected in which all of it had a particular name common to all of them, what i want to do is that name sould appear only once since it's common to all the rows.

Comment: Major security issue: `WHERE main_table.matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]'";` Unsanitized post variable going straight into the database.

Comment: @KanyinsolaOyesanmi Can you specify the field names you want to display only one time?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion to your question since I don't know which field you want to stop duplicating. Here I am proposing you a way to stop printing the first_name if it is duplicating again and again. Here you have to make sure your query is ordered by that value set as well.

Please tr this code.

**EDITED**.

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
 <?php require('includes/dbconnect.php'); ?>
 <?php require 'includes/header.inc.php'; ?>
<?php
 $matric_no = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matric_no']) ;
 if ( $_POST['matric_no'] == "")
{
 echo"<div id=\"contentRight\">";
 echo"<div id=\"msg\">" ;
 echo "You didn't enter a <span style=\"color:red\"> Matric Number</span>";
 echo"</div>" ;
 echo"</div>" ;
  exit();
 }
  $query = "SELECT matric_no
 FROM main_table
     WHERE main_table.matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]'";
   $result = mysql_query($query) ;
  $duplicates = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if ($duplicates < 1)
{
 echo"<div id=\"contentRight\">";
echo"<idv id=\"msg\">" ;
 echo "You dont have a record for <span style=\"color:red\">
   $matric_no</span>" ;
 echo"</div>" ;
  echo"</div>" ;
  exit();
 }
{
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT main_table.matric_no ,
  main_table.session,
  main_table.semester , main_table.course_name ,
  (test+exam+practical) AS Total,
  students.first_name, students.last_name, students.other_name,
  students.level
  FROM main_table INNER JOIN students ON
  main_table.matric_no = students.matric_no
   WHERE main_table.matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]' ORDER BY students.first_name")
  or die (mysql_error());

  $matchingString = "";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       echo $row["matric_no"] ;                   
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row["session"]; echo "<br />";
  echo $row["semester"];
  echo "<br />";
   echo $row["course_name"];
   echo "<br />";
   $checkingString = $row["first_name"] . $row["last_name"] . $row["other_name"] . $row["level"];

   if($matchingString != $checkingString)
   {
    echo $row["first_name"];
    echo "<br />";  
    echo $row["last_name"];
  echo "<br />";
    echo $row["other_name"];
  echo "<br />";
    echo $row["level"]; echo "<br />";
    $matchingString = $checkingString;
    }
   }
  }
 ?>
```

**ANSWER AFTER THE QUESTION MODIFICATION**

Just change your two loops as bellow and see.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < ($number_cols - 4); $i++)
```

Comment: The fields i want to stop duplicating... first_name, last_name, other_name, level from the students table.

Comment: Tahnks for the help, but i still dosent do what i want it to do. I have uploaded it for you to see. You'll notice that in the cell labeled 1 the iteration occured and they are the same, which i dont really want, but i just want it to appear in the cell labelled 2. Which will be in a form of a title block for the fesult print out.

Thanks

http://www.ziddu.com/download/18541825/Untitled.png.html

Comment: Please check your code in the question and the out put. I feel something is missing in your question. Your out put seems like a HTML table. but here you just separate things with <br/>. I feel you only have a small issue, but you can't tell it exactly. Try..

Comment: I added an answer containing all the codes i have which contained like you rightly said the HTML Table. Thanks for the help.

Comment: See the edited answer of mine. I mean last couple of lines of my answer. Please delete your 2nd post on this thread since it is not the answer. Thanks.

Comment: i implemented like you rightly said, and it did removed the field entry for the identical iteration, while retaining the column heading.

Comment: You have to modify both for loops.

Comment: Will it be sensible if i make two different database calls. One will for returning all the rows that should normally return (matric_no, course, semester, session, total), while the other one will be just for the item containing (first_name, last_name, other_name, level), since they are all unique to a particular student then it will only be one row returned then i'll be able to work with the data as i want. Will this make a logical sense? And also wont it run down my database as the data gets enormous? Thanks for the help.